# Evaluating this limit in Fourier analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fractals

In my research work related to Fourier transform of the standard Cantor measure, I came across the following elementary problem: 
For $k\geq 1$, let
$$
S_k=\sum_{m=0}^{3^k-1}\,\,\,\prod_{j=1}^\infty \cos^2\left(\frac {2m \pi}{3^j}\right).
$$
We would like to find the following limit:
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\log(S_k)}{k}.
$$
Let us first see why the limit exists. Let 
$$\phi(m)=\prod_{j=1}^\infty \cos^2\left(\frac {2m \pi}{3^j}\right).
$$
We know that $\phi(m)<1$, so $S_k<3^k$. By self-symmetry, we also have $\phi(3m)=\phi(m)$, and hence $S_k>r^k$ for some $0<r<3$. Then we know that $\frac{\log(S_k)}{k}\to r$ for some $r<3$.

My question is: can we evaluate the above limit precisely?

(Edited twice)

Comment: It seems your estimates only show that $c<\log S_k/k<3$, not that the limit exists.

Comment: I have edited my post. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This ($S_k$ increasing and $< 3^k$) still doesn't seem sufficient to guarantee existence of $\lim\log S_k/k$, though. (Of course, it's perfectly ok to just state that there are reasons why the limit exists if that's the case, but your formulation suggests that you've presented the complete argument.)